# node.js + jade - link is self closing and should not have content

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm referring the following great tutorial on MEAN stack.

Now I'm facing a template(JADE) related issue which I'm not able to resolve :(
Can you plz have a look and help me if possible.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-nodejs-polling-app/

```
    doctype 5
    html(lang='en')
      head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no')
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/
css/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')                
      body
        nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
          div.navbar-header
            a.navbar-brand(href='#/polls')= title
        div.container
          div
```

I'm getting this exception. Tried couple of varitions but couldn't resolve it yet.

```
Error: C:\DevEnv\UT3_Node\HelloWorldNodeProject\views\index.jade:14
    12|         a.navbar-brand(href='#/polls')= title
    13|     div.container
  > 14|       div

**link is self closing and should not have content.**
```

Thanks in adv.

Comment: `a.navbar-brand(href='#/polls')= title` remove space before `title`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
```

You can't see it very well on StackOverflow, but you have a bunch of whitespace after the tag.

The whitespace is shown here replaced with `_`:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')________________
```

So your Jade would generate something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">________________</link>
```

which is not allowed, since `<link>` elements are not allowed to have child nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any standard jade template checker which you use/recommend? 
thanks again.

Comment: Strange, I have the same error, but no whitespace. Can link tags not be followed by meta tags?

Comment: the example "express" created project uses jade as template!  Jade has problems with editors (my observation!).  Use Swig don't use Jade for templates

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

```
a.navbar-brand(href='#/polls')= title
```

remove space before `title`

```
a.navbar-brand(href='#/polls')=title
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one of the examples in the Practical Node.js text. The root cause was my error - using double quotes in a link definition instead of single quotes. The challenge was that the message (link is self closing and should not have content.) was appearing on a div statement and hence was very confusing. It turns out that the error was in my include file rather than where jade indicated. The line number was correct, but it was showing the wrong file content. Once I had that figured out, the fix was easy. 
 Seems to be a bug in the JADE compiler.